# How to get firebase to store files in order by date?

Tags: firebase, sorting, iteration, firebase-storage

I was saving files to firebase storage and I noticed that firebase is saving the items in random order. I was wondering if there was a way to get the files to be in order by date, for interation purposes, or do the user have to place the files in order by date by comparing dates ?I have seen a similar post , but using firebase database which doesn't fit my usecase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Storage doesn't define an order to objects it stores.  If you want an order, you will have to impose one yourself.

You could put some sort of formatted timestamp in the name of each object, then you would be able to sort them on the client app after you [list them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files).  Again, *Cloud Storage will not sort them for you*.  Its job is to just store objects with unique paths.

You could also write something to a database for each object you write, then query the database as needed.  This is the more common and flexible option.

Comment: How does Storage actually sort them? By IDs? Because I always receive the same order in the client side, they are not randomized.

Comment: They are sorted by filename.